# drop ips with iptables from awk result

Tags: iptables, ip, awk, filter

I have a log file like this :

```
Frq:15 IP:0.0.0.0 Date: 2014-03-21 12:19:31 AM
Frq:9 IP:198.252.206.25 Date: 2014-03-21 12:19:31 AM
```

Now i get column of ip addresses with awk :

```
cat /tmp/test | awk '{print $2}'|awk '{gsub("IP:", "");print}'
```

And the result is :

```
0.0.0.0
198.252.206.25
```

I want add this ip addresses into iptables to be DROP from INPUT but i dont know how

Thanks friends.

Comment: I used awk '{gsub("IP:", "");print}' to remove IP:

Comment: Save a cat. `awk '{print $2}'|awk '{gsub("IP:", "");print}' /tmp/test`

Comment: Lets just hope you dont have 127.0.0.1 in there..

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?

Comment: @AaronCopley: +1, but save an `awk`, too, as in opsguy's answer - or: `awk -F '[: ]' '{print $4}'`

Comment: Good point. I didn't look at it any more closely than the `cat | awk`. Not sure I would have caught it anyway. Still a little green with awk. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt:

```
awk '{sub("IP:", "", $2); print $2}' /tmp/test | xargs -n1 -I{} iptables -A INPUT -s {} -j DROP
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll be farther ahead by extending [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) by dropping in a custom configuration file into its `.d` config directory.

Do as little work as possible!

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a script that will loop over your `awk` result and creates appropriate `iptables` rules on the fly :

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /tmp/test | awk '{print $2}'|awk '{gsub("IP:", "");print}' | while read IP
do
  iptables -A INPUT -s $IP -j DROP
done
```

However, i don't know your context and how your log file can be trusted, but it is dangerous and you should survey which IPs you are dropping.

For a sample, the following makes an exception for `127.0.0.1` :

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /tmp/test | awk '{print $2}'|awk '{gsub("IP:", "");print}' | while read IP
do
  if [ "$IP" != "127.0.0.1" ]; then
    iptables -A INPUT -s $IP -j DROP
  fi
done
```